# jQuery apply css to all elements with id x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to apply css to all `p` elements which contain more than one digits, for example:

```
<p id="winddir_text" >5 </p>    <!-- don't apply css -->
<p id="winddir_text"> 12 </p>   <!-- apply css -->
<p id="winddir_text"> 48 </p>   <!-- apply css -->
```

**My jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pString = $("#winddir_text").text();
var pLength = (pString).length;
if (pLength > 1)
    $("#winddir_text").css({"top": "33px", "left": "32px", "font-size": "30px"});
});
```

This code only applies the css to the first element with id `winddir_text`. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Use classes instead of an id. An id can only be on the page once.

Comment: Also, add a class to the elements and put the rules in an external stylesheet. You should avoid using `css()` unless there's no alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iN This case you should use class instead of Id .

```
<p class="winddir_text" >5 </p>    <!-- don't apply css -->
<p class="winddir_text"> 12 </p>   <!-- apply css -->
<p class="winddir_text"> 48 </p>   <!-- apply css -->
```

Then target class using each loop.

```
$(".winddir_text").each(function(){
  var pString = $(this).text();
  var pLength = (pString).length;
  if (pLength > 1)
    $(this).css({"top": "33px", "left": "32px", "font-size": "30px"});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code and use class as handler instead of ID.

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if( parseInt($(this).text()) > 9) {
    // $(this).css();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find all the `p` elements on the page and itterate through them all. jQuery provides a function for this: `$.each`.

```
$('p').each(function() {
  var length = $(this).text().trim().length;
  if (length > 1) {
    $("#winddir_text").css({"top": "33px", "left": "32px", "font-size": "30px"});
  }
});
```

This will only affect the first `#windir_text` because you are using IDs instead of something like classes. You can easily change those and the selector to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change those id's to classes instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ps = $(".winddir_text");
  $(ps).each(function() {
    var len = $(this).text().trim().length;
    if (len > 1) {
      $(this).css({
        top: "33px",
        left: "32px",
        "font-size": "30px"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="winddir_text" >5 </p>    <!-- don't apply css -->
<p class="winddir_text"> 12 </p>   <!-- apply css -->
<p class="winddir_text"> 48 </p>   <!-- apply css -->
```